# Polynomials are linearly independent iff rows of $A$ are linearly independent where $P(x)=A[x^k]$

Tags: linear-algebra

Polynomials are linearly independent iff rows of $A$ are linearly independent where $P(x)=A[x^k]_{k=1,\cdots,n}$. I know how to prove this but is there higher level intuition of why this is true? i.e. polynomials are no different from tuples/vectors in $R^n$

Comment: How about if you don't think of polynomials but think of row vectors conjoined into a matrix?

Comment: @Robert can you make it an answer?